# Coverting pdf to csv syntax error

Tags: python, csv, pdf

Why do I keep getting this error message

> File "sfctabcvrt.py", line 3 cat test.csv #view the contents of the
>   test.csv file SyntaxError: invalid syntax

when I try to run this code in Linux:

```
from tabula import convert_into
convert_into("Trialpage.pdf", "test.csv", output_format="csv") 
cat test.csv #view the contents of the test.csv file
```

Comment: Put a space after #

Answer (score 1):

*Cat* is not a python statement.

Add this in the first line of your script

```
import os
```

Replace the line which contains the cat command by this one:

```
os.system("cat test.csv")
```

Comment: I am a novice at coding, how would I implement your suggestion into my initial code?

Comment: thank you. I followed your instructions now I have a different error. Now Linux is giving me this error "File "sfctabcvrt.py", line 2, in <module>, from tabula import convert_into, ImportError: No module named tabula"

Comment: however when I did a pip install of tabula-py it states that the "Requirement is already satisfied" and it lists a path to a local library for python 3.5

Comment: I actually figured out issue the tabula-py module was installed on python 3 while I was working with python 2.7  so once I changed the version on python the code ran, not with much success however.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out issue the tabula-py module was installed on python 3 while I was working with python 2.7 so once I changed the version the code executed.